# Play 1.2.5 - Load Initial Data with Custom ID

Tags: playframework, yaml

So, I have a model with a custom ID, something like this:

```csharp
@Entity
public class SomeModel extends Model {

    @Id
    @Unique
    @Required
    public String myOwnId;

    @Required
    public String someOtherField;

    public SomeModel(final String myOwnId, final String someOtherField) {
        this.myOwnId = myOwnId;
        this.someOtherField = someOtherField;
    }

}
```

And I have a initial-data.yml file that goes like this:

```csharp
SomeModel(myModel):
  myOwnId: "someID"
  someOtherField: "some value here"
```

This, however, doesn't work: `RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture initial-data.yml: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of models.SomeModel.id`. Any nice and simple solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad, it actually works, however, you have to extend `GenericModel`, not `Model` with your model class.